# How to display the Soft Keyboard in Air Debug Launcher (ADL)

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, flex4.5, flex-mobile

I've searched Google for about 1,5h now and i can't find a good answer.
Is it possible to display the Soft Keyboard when debugging using ADL?
If i use the existing properties I still don't see it.

I want to check if my layout looks well when the Soft Keyboard appears, but for some reason I don't see it coming in ADL (Adobe Debug Launcher).
I don't have a tablet to test it on for now so that isn't a solution.

Am i doing something wrong whereby I don't see the soft keyboard or doesn't it exist in ADL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ADL is just the Flex debugger program.  When I use ADL to launch my app on an Android device; there are no issues getting the soft keyboard to show up.  When I use ADL to launch an app in an emulator, I have never seen the soft keyboard come up.  [This is not supported with the emulator included with Flex / Flash Builder](http://forums.adobe.com/message/3736890).

In my experience the availability of the soft keyboard depends on the context you're running the app in (Debugger vs Device) and has nothing to do w/ ADL.

Does that answer your question?

Comment: Yes it is. Thanx for the answer. Didn't find the link in your answer on Google last night. Thanks for sharing it.